# javascript singleton object per string

Tags: javascript, oop, singleton, design-patterns

I want to create an object which is singleton per a string. For example when I call `myObject("string1")` it always returns the same object but different from `myObject("string2")`.

Comment: how do you want to define _which_ object is returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var MyObject = function(){
    var objs = {};

    return function(str){
        if( objs[str] ){
            return objs[str];
        }else{
            objs[str] = function(){
                //some code here
            };
            return objs[str];
        }
    };
}();
```

Comment: It worked, but what I don't understand is why objs which is private object is acting az a global object? why everytime MyObject is being called objs is NOT setting to a new {} object?

Comment: Notice the last () in the fragment. The function will run immediately and MyObject is the inner function actually. The objs is hold by the reference in the inner function, and will not be destruction. It is call **clouser**  in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do something like this (following your `myObject(name)` API example):

```
var myObject = (function (){
  var objects = {
    "myString1": {
      name: "myString One Object"
      //...
    },
    "myString2": {
      name: "myString Two Object"
      //...
    }
  };
  //...
  return function (name) { // the actual function
    return objects[name];  // that retrieves the object
  };                       // by its "name" (e.g. 'myString1')
})();


myObject("myString1").name;  // "myString One Object"
myObject("myString1") === myObject("myString1"); // true, the same object ref.
myObject("myString2").name;  // "myString Two Object"
```

Comment: The strings should not be predefined , I want to use it for every string.

Answer (score 1):

Create an object with the strings as properties and assign whatever value suits:

```
var myObject = {
  'string1': ... ,
  'string2': ... ,
  'string3': ... ,
   ...
};
```

Then access them by the string:

```
alert( myObject['string1'] ); // whatever
```